# Get list of types for each key in object

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I'm starting to learn the basics of Python machine learning with the iris dataset. I load the dataset with the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset = load_iris()
```

I then start to look at the shape of each key, but some keys are a list and do not have a shape. So I look at the type of each key with `type(iris_dataset['feature_names'])`. However, I don't want to repeat this code for each key. Is it possible to get the type of each key within this iris object? I tried this but it obviously does not work:

```
In [30]: type(iris_dataset.keys())
Out[30]: dict_keys
```

Comment: you could use a list comprehension `[type(k) for k in iris_dataset]` note that assuming iris_dataset is a dictionary it automatically returns its keys in a for loop, so you needn't explicitly call `.keys()`

Comment: Try: `for key in iris_dataset:
 print("type of {}: {}".format(key, type(key)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I look at the type of each key with `type(iris_dataset['feature_names'])`

Note: It seems like you want the types of all the *values* to the different keys, not the types of the keys *themselves*.

You can use a list comprehension, applying the `type` function for each key in the data:

```
[type(iris_dataset[key]) for key in iris_dataset]
```

However, assuming that `iris_dataset` is some kind of `dict`, the keys might have any order, so having a list of types alone does not yet tell you which type corresponded to the value of what key. Instead, you might prefer a list of tuples `(key, type)`:

```
[(key, type(iris_dataset[key])) for key in iris_dataset]
```

Comment: @leaf the only thing i can think of is that with the first one you instantly know `iris_dataset` is a dictionary and not a `list` or `tuple`

Comment: @leaf I agree. this is the only "advantage" i see. i like the less verbose version better as well. And Python 2 is ok with it too.

Comment: @leaf It is not more or less "verbose", it is doing something else entirely. [type(key) ...]` gets the types of the keys, while `[type(data[key]) ...]` gets the types of the values, which in my impression is what OP really wanted.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion guys, I believe it is the types of all the values to the different keys. For example, `type(iris_dataset['feature_names'])` gives the value of `list`. I want to repeat that for each key in the object.

Comment: @tobias_k Sorry man. I don't know how I missed that. I wasn't paying attention to what you were doing. I feel like a complete idiot now.

Comment: At least all of you know what you're doing,... :D

Answer (score 0):

You can map the type built-in to the keys of the dict, and wrap the `map()` in a `list()` to get a list back:

`dict_key_types = list(map(type, iris_dataset.keys()))`